# std::stringstream.str() is always the same string being returned?

Tags: c++

When creating a `std::stringstream` and filling it with data, can I rely on the same string object being returned as long as the stream is not changed anymore?

To illustrate what I mean, consider this example:

```
std::stringstream ss;

ss << value1;
ss << value2;
...

std::vector<char> data(ss.str().begin(), ss.str().end());
```

Now in the case of the vector being filled, is this valid or will `stringstream` always create a new string object?

So would it be better/safer/correct to do it like this and have an additional copy operation?

```
std::string s = ss.str();
std::vector<char> data(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Comment: There are high quality online references (e.g. cppreference.com) that tell you what functions in the standard library return, **use them**! "What does this standard function return?" should not be a question on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[The documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) is your friend. Use it!*

`std::basic_stringstream::str()` returns by value (i.e. a copy), so what you're doing is not safe.

You could create your own local as in your example (and rely on RVO), or you could bind the result to a ref-to-`const`:

```
const std::string& s = ss.str();
std::vector<char> data(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Comment: I thought as much, just wanted to be sure. Thx!

Comment: Binding temporary object to const reference extends object's lifetime to match the reference's lifetime, so this is safe

Comment: @M.M It's not _always_ safe. There are occasions where the binding doesn't get you what you expect. I just can't remember off the top of my head what they are.

Comment: If the function returned by reference it would not be safe..  let me know if you think of what you were thinking :)

Comment: @M.M: "`[C++14: 12.2/5]:` The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement." This passage is unclear to me. I guess it's relating to binding a reference to a `return`d temporary and then bound again, but I keep going back-and-forth on this stuff. I have therefore become very wary about it. I remember seeing a related and surprising SO answer the other day, but can't find it now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that refers to e.g. `T &foo() { return T(); }` and it is saying that the `T()` temporary is destroyed at the end of the `return` statement; it does not live long enough for the calling code to use it.  Doesn't apply to returning by value, as the return-value object is move constructed from the return expression

Comment: @M.M: Yes I know; but you asked me to tell you what I was thinking of, so I did :P With a tangential observation that I think the wording can be improved.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's quite simple if you just consider the caller and the function body separately, and don't over-language-lawyer it. Outside the function the caller can always bind a reference to the function return, because either it returns by value (and so you will extend the lifetime of that object) or it returns a reference, which the caller must assume is a valid reference or you already have UB and the caller can't do anything about it anyway. Inside the function, binding a reference to a temporary is obviously bad, you're returning a reference to a local. Don't do that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: As I said, I could have sworn there was another, confusing/surprising case, that came up on SO the other day. The basic cases are pretty obvious, but until I can remember what that case was I'm going to be wary. Still, I can't find any evidence of it now, so perhaps I dreamt it...

Answer (score 3):

Your second attempt is correct (and probably the best you can really do, if we are using string streams).

As for the first attempt...
That isn't valid, as far as I can tell.
This site http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/
says:

```
string str() const;
```

Which means it returns a new string by value.

If it returned a string&, you'd get away with it.

You also asked 
"So would it be better/safer/correct to do it like this and have an additional copy operation?"

but you may have overlooked the fact that both "ss.str" calls would allocate a new string each time.

It's a shame that there's no obvious way to get a vector out of a stringstream (without going via a string).